# how to use spark_apply_bundle

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to use `spark_apply_bundle` to limit the number of `packages/data` transferred to the worker nodes on a `YARN` managed cluster. As mentioned in [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/0.7.0/topics/spark_apply) I must pass the path of the `tarball` to `spark_apply` as the packages argument and I also must make it available via `"sparklyr.shell.files"` in the spark config.

My questions are:

- Can the path to the tarball be relative to the project's working directory, if not then should it be stored on hdfs or somewhere else?
- What should be passed to `"sparklyr.shell.files"`? Is it a duplicate of the path passed to `spark_apply`?

Currently my unsuccessful script look something like this:

```
bundle <- paste(getwd(), list.files()[grep("\\.tar$",list.files())][1], sep = "/")

...

config$sparklyr.shell.files <- bundle
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = config)

...

spark_apply(sdf, f, packages = bundle)
```

Answer (score 2):

The spark job succeeded by copying the tarball to hdfs. It seems as if it's plausible to use some other method (e.g. copying the file to each worker node) but this seems to be the easiest solution.

The updated script looks as follows:

```
bundle <- paste(getwd(), list.files()[grep("\\.tar$",list.files())][1], sep = "/")

...

hdfs_path <- "hdfs://nn.example.com/some/directory/"
hdfs_bundle <- paste0(hdfs_path, basename(bundle))
system(paste("hdfs dfs -put", bundle, hdfs_path))
config$sparklyr.shell.files <- hdfs_bundle
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = config)

...

spark_apply(sdf, f, packages = bundle)
```

Comment: Could you provide the sample working code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68444612/distributing-the-r-library-across-the-hadoop-worker-nodes-spark-hadoop?noredirect=1#comment120963037_68444612