# How to use packages in spark_apply in R?

Tags: r, sparklyr

I require to use R packages with `spark_apply` function in the `sparklyr` package. The [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/0.7.0/topics/spark_apply) is not quite clear. I tried to make `spark_apply` work by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717181/how-to-use-spark-apply-bundle). It worked for the first part with the following modifications.

The working part:

```
library(sparklyr)

spark_apply_bundle(packages = T, base_path = getwd())

bundle <- paste(getwd(), list.files()[grep("\\.tar$",list.files())][1], sep = "/")

hdfs_path <- "hdfs://<my-ip>/user/hadoop/R/packages/packages.tar"
system("hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal", bundle, "hdfs://<my-ip>/user/hadoop/R/packages")

config <- spark_config()

config$sparklyr.shell.files <- "hdfs://<my-ip>/user/hadoop/R/packages/packages.tar"

sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", 
                    version = "2.4.0", 
                    config = config)
mtcars_sparklyr <- copy_to(sc, mtcars)
```

However, when I try to use `svm` function within the `spark_apply`, it does not work using the `packages` argument.

```
result <- mtcars_sparklyr %>%
  spark_apply(
    function(d) {
      fit <- svm(d$mpg, d$wt)
      sum(fit$residuals ^ 2)
      },
    group_by = "cyl",
    packages = bundle
  )
```

The following, on the other hand, works. This is if I pass the `svm` function within the `context`. However, I require the `packages` argument to work because I have several packages and their functions to use within the `spark_apply`.

```
result <- mtcars_sparklyr %>%
  spark_apply(
    function(d) {
      fit <- svm(d$mpg, d$wt)
      sum(fit$residuals ^ 2)
    },
    group_by = "cyl",
    context = {svm <- e1071::svm}
  )
```

Comment: Any luck on getting this working?  One possible suggestion is to load the library inside of the function rather than trying to use context to do it.

function(d) {
     library(e1071)
     fit <- e1071::svm(d$mpg, d$wt)
     sum(fit$reisduals^2)
},
group_by = "cyl")